# What is "being out of job for a personal reason" called?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

After I finished my study, I had to chose not to do any job because I had **to take care of my parent**. The period took 3 years. And then I was back free to have a job. What is that period called.

On the Internet I found *Personal leave, carer’s leave, compassionate leave, family leave* and *career break*. Which one is more appropriate for me to put in my resume for those 3 years?

Comment: _Leave_ implies that you were given time off by an employer (leave of absence), so I think you would have to call it a career break.

Comment: In the UK you're just "economically inactive", so far as the taxman is concerned. Is it really necessary to explain exactly what you were doing? Maybe you were struggling with mental health problems, and/or spent time in prison. Whatever - all that matters is you weren't in paid employment with someone who might confirm this with a reference. Prospective employers don't need to know any more than that.

Comment: *Career break* ("a period of time when you do not do your usual job, for example because you have children to care for" -- https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/career-break); sounds best to me. See also, https://www.hrzone.com/hr-glossary/what-is-a-career-break . *Sabbatical* works, too, if the context is otherwise clear.

Comment: I also think *career break* is the best, but you will likely have to add a some explanation what it was for, e.g. *Jan 2017 to  Feb 2019 . Career break (Caring for ill relative).*

Comment: don't put any of that on a resume... put self-employed

Comment: You could be *on hiatus*...

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want to put the best face on things, *compassionate leave* and *family leave* seem best of the alternatives you listed, even though as noted in a comment you were not actually on a "leave".

[*Career break*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Career_break) as described in Wikipedia seems neutral and applicable, although three years is a longer term than that entry mentions.

If you were an actor, the euphemism *resting* would apply.  If you were previously employed and returned to the same employer, [*sabbatical*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatical) might be appropriate.  Other terms for gaps include *hiatus* and [*interregnum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interregnum), the latter more applicable if you are a government or royalty.  Or you could say you were *slacking*, but some regard that as not good on a resume.

Answer (score 1):

As in this article:

> 1999   Washington Post (Electronic ed.) 18 June   In a world where
>   everyone has sick days, **personal leave** and mental health breaks,
>   12 years of perfect attendance is a rare feat.

Personal leave if frequently referenced in AmE to absences from work due to 'personal' reasons, which you may or may choose not to elaborate on.